# Which symbols should not be allowed in forms?

Tags: html, forms

I know "quotes" should be omitted because they let hackers write code for cross-client execution. Are there any other symbols that should be avoided?

Comment: You *should* be escaping all user-generated content that gets printed, so all symbols should be allowed. If this is an issue, your code is broken and needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ALL** symbols should be allowed.  You need to make sure that you are escaping them properly.